# how to union two table in obiee?

Tags: union, obiee

I have two tables in my physical layer(due some reason) although I konw it's better two union two tables.Table A and Table B has same structure。I aim to implement a sql like：

```
select F1，F2 
     from (select *
           from tableA
           union
           select *
           from tableB)
tableMix
```

just union two factor table...how can I do it in Admin tools?

now the nqquery like that

```
WITH SAWITH0 AS
    ((select T3580.AMOUNT as c1, T30887.YEAR_DESC as c2, T30887.YEAR_WID as c3
      from DW_DAY_D T30887 /* A_Dim_DW_TQ_DAY_D */, DW_TQ_PRODUCT_F T3580 /*                    A_Fact_DW_TQ_PRODUCT_F */
      where (T3580.DAY_ID = T30887.DAY_WID)
      union all
      select T120596.AMOUNT   as c1,
      T30887.YEAR_DESC as c2,
      T30887.YEAR_WID  as c3
      from DW_DAY_D T30887 /* A_Dim_DW_TQ_DAY_D */, DW_MHG_PRODUCT_F T120596 /*      A_Fact_DW_MHG_PRODUCT_F */
      where (T30887.DAY_WID = T120596.DAY_ID))),
      SAWITH1 AS
     (select distinct D3.c1 as c1, D3.c2 as c2, D3.c3 as c3 from SAWITH0 D3)
     select distinct 0 as c1, D2.c2 as c2, D2.c1 as c3, D2.c3 as c4
     from SAWITH1 D2
     order by c4, c3
```

but I can't set the aggration rule as 'sum' on 'amount'.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
You can create a opaque view in the physical layer. The view would be query you've mentioned in your post.

Option 2:
In the BMM layer, create a logical table (tableMix) with two logical tables sources (tableA and tableB).

Comment: thanks for answer.Due some reason,Option 1 can't be used.Now I'm trying opton 2,but now facing a problem when I try to set aggregation rule as 'sum',it reports a error called 'nQSError 15001',could you explain your steps by detail?thanks very much

Comment: Make sure that this option is enabled on both logical table sources: "This source should be combined with other sources at this level" on the content tab

Comment: I'm sure the option is enabled,and i feel confused in the fragment content.now new nqquery like that as above.when I try to set aggregation rule as 'sum',it reports a error called 'nQSError 15001'

Comment: What is it that you exactly want? Maybe there is a better solution.